# Segmenation Fault (Core Dumped) in following code

Tags: segmentation-fault

Given the following structure and function:

```
typedef struct VectorT 

{

        NodeT **list;
        int   capacity;
        int   size;
 } VectorT;


VectorT* newVector(int capacity)

{

        struct  VectorT *vector;
        *vector->list = (NodeT*) malloc(capacity * sizeof(NodeT));
        vector->capacity = capacity;
        vector->size = 0;
        return vector;
}
```

Please explain why I get a segmentation fault when the function is called.

After some trial and error with this function and another function, I believe it has something to do with how I am accessing the "**list". I can comment out the areas that have to do with **list and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Why do people insist in providing answers in comment boxes? If it's not _worthy_ of an answer, it should probably just be deleted. As Yoda would say, "answer, or answer not, there is no try" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first must initialize your vector, like so

```
struct  VectorT *vector=(struct VectorT*)malloc(sizeof(struct VectorT));
```

Also, your line that is initializing the list should be:

```
vector->list = (NodeT**) malloc(capacity * sizeof(NodeT*));
```

But if your list should be declared as "NodeT* list;" instead of NodeT** you could initialize it with:

```
vector->list = (NodeT*) malloc(capacity * sizeof(NodeT));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is the problem:

```
*vector->list = (NodeT*) malloc(capacity * size`of(NodeT));
```

you're trying to de-reference something that isn't a pointer yet. You need to allocate memory for your `VectorT`

```
VectorT* newVector(int capacity)
{
  VectorT *vector = malloc(sizeof(VectorT));
  vector->list = malloc(capacity * sizeof(NodeT));
  vector->capacity = capacity;
  vector->size = 0;
  return vector;
}
```

In real world code you're going to want to check the return value of `malloc`. Depending on if you are using `C` or `C++` you'll need to cast the return value of `malloc`

Comment: I am still getting segmentation fault with these changes.